# Having trouble with making a circular button in CSS

Tags: css

My current code in CSS for this button is:

```
button.new-comic { 
  border-radius:50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

For some reason, the shape of the button refuses to go down to a circle, though numerous sites that I've searched only used border-radius. If border-radius didn't work, they used border-collapse. However, neither of these are working for me at all, and I'm unable to come up with any other ideas.

Any help would be appreciated!
(I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using Chrome)

Comment: try giving min-width and max-width too..

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a minimum amount of code, it could be that there are some other properties defined elsewhere. You can check Computed styles in the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: @Leventix thanks for the wake up call! :P A litt tired obviously! :P You could provide the HTML where you try to add this style, so we could more easily help you out. This pen works fine with your CSS: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVGaGQ

Comment: Sorry! I used this for my jade:
`code`
button.btn.btn-link.new-comic(title='Add New Comic', type='button')
      span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign.glyphicon-new-comic(aria-hidden='true')

Basically, I'm trying to make a round button with an image the glyphicon. However, when I click near the edges of the circle button (where the edges of a square typically are), I can still activate the button. I'm trying to make it so that the button can only be clicked when I'm clicking on the circle...